# Update multiple record using one query

Tags: sql

I want to update records in a dynamic way.

How to write update query in single quote value separate show in query

```
SET @query = 'UPDATE @table SET @col1 = 'ABC' WHERE @col2 = 552;
              UPDATE @table SET @col1 = 'BCA' WHERE @col2 = 553;
              UPDATE @table SET @col1 = 'MBA' WHERE @col2 = 554;'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` -

```
UPDATE @table
SET @col1 = 
CASE WHEN @col2 = 552 THEN 'ABC'
     WHEN @col2 = 553 THEN 'BCA'
     WHEN @col2 = 554 THEN 'MBA'
END
WHERE @col2 in (552, 553, 554)
```

If you want to escape single quote in SQL you can do it by prefixing additional single quote i.e. `'`

> Example - 'Hi, my name''s Nikhil.'